# React-tooltip doesn't show on conditional render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-tooltip

[`react-tooltip`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-tooltip) is awesome, but I'm running into issues with a conditionally rendered component.

I have a refresh icon that only shows when `props.refreshImages` is `true`:

*Topbar.js*

```
import React from 'react'

export default function Topbar (props) {
  return (
    <div>
      {props.refreshImages && 
      <i data-tip="Refresh the images" className="fas fa-sync-alt" ></i>}
    </div>
  )
}
```

*App.js*

```
import React from 'react'
import Topbar from './Topbar'
import ReactTooltip from 'react-tooltip'

export default function App() {
  return (
    <ReactTooltip />
    <Topbar refreshImages={true}/>
  )
}
```

Simplified example. But when the refresh icon is hidden and shown again (`props.refreshImages` is `false` and then `true`) the tooltips don't display.

I've already tried moving `<ReactTooltip />` into *Topbar.js* and running *ReactTooltip.rebuild()* on every render, none have worked. For `props.refreshImages` I'm actually using Redux.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

**You need to rebuild your tooltips with ReactTooltip.rebuild post a render and not before it.**

Assuming you are using functional components with hooks, you can do so with useEffect hooks

```
export default function App(props) {
  useEffect(() => {
      ReactTooltip.rebuild();
  }, [props.refreshImages])
  return (
    <ReactTooltip />
    <Topbar refreshImages={props.refreshImages}/>
  )
}
```

or with a class component you would write the logic in `componentDidUpdate`

```
 componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if(prevProps.showItem !== this.props.showItem) {
      ReactTooltip.rebuild();
    }
  }
```

[Sample demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-tooltip-example-3116-ik2mf)

Answer (score 1):

Use this
import { Tooltip as ReactTooltip } from 'react-tooltip'

Answer (score 0):

ReactTooltip.rebuild();

add this in componentDidUpdate function whenever state will update the function will callup and rebuild the Tooltip